# Point doubling for a point on Elliptic Curve (15,13) + (15,13) = (2,)

Tags: elliptic-curves

Consider the elliptic curve E1:y2=x3+7 over F17 with the base point G=(15,13)

I am trying to compute point double of (15,13) i.e (15,13)+ (15,13)
Expected point is (2,10) , however I am not able to calcualate it.
Could anyone point out where I am making mistake

s = 3 * (15*15) / 2 * 13 mod 17 = 375/26 mod 17 = 750 mod 17 = 2

x3 = (2*2) - 15 -15 mod 17 = -26 mod 17  = 8

y3 = 2(15-8) - 13 mod 17 = 1

however point x3,y3 = 8,1 does not lie on Elliptic curve
Please help me understand this point doubling operation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think something went wrong in your 2nd "equals". 3*15*15 is not 375

Comment: could you please be exact :  i just did 3 * 125 /26 = 375/26

Comment: 3*15*15 = 3*(225) you calculate 3*(5^3) or something like that

Comment: Yes , I am essentially  trying to compute the same thing wrt to this point (15,13) on the said curve . I undertstand the my s calucation is incorrect ..but not sure how exactly.My explanation is inverse of 26 mod 17 is 2 ..hence 375 * 2  = 750.could you please correct ?

Comment: The formulas to apply are in [sec1v2 §2.2.1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1), case 5, which uses $\lambda$ where the question has $s$. The first issue in the question is that 3*(15*15) is 675, not 375. [reposted with correction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 3 * (15*15) / 2 * 13 mod 17 = 375/26 mod 17 = 750 mod 17 = 2
```

This is not correct ($3\cdot 225 = 675 \neq 375$). The correct one is;

$s = \frac{3 (x_1^2)}{2 y_1 } =  \frac{3 (15^2)}{2\cdot 13 }= \frac{3 (-2)^2}{2\cdot 13 }=  \frac{3 \cdot 4}{2\cdot 13 }=  12 \cdot 26^{-1}  = 12 \cdot 2 = 24 = 7\bmod 17$

Therefore;

$x_3 = s^2 - 2 \cdot x_1 =  49 - 2 \cdot 15 = -2 + 4 = 2\bmod 17$

---

We used the doubling formula on the affine formulas as with $a = 0$ with as in Secp256k1

Let  $$y^2 = x^3  + b$$ be the curve equation then the doubling formula is

\begin{align}
x_3 = & s^2 -2 x_1  & \mod p\\
y_3 = & s(x_1-x_3) -y_1 & \mod p
\end{align}

$$
s = \frac{3 x_1^2}{2y_1} \bmod p
$$

Comment: How thanks for your explantion . I understood your calculations and also my mistake.

Comment: Using the negatives helps to reduce the calculations, like $15 = -2 \bmod 17$ so you don't need the large number and reduce it.